CDs are ejected after insertion - Ubuntu Cinnamon 24.04
I am running Ubuntu Cinnamon 24.04 on an Alienware x51 with an integrated DVD drive. Whenever I insert any CD, it is ejected after a couple of seconds. I can find no information on any issue in syslog or the kernel ring buffer suggesting an issue, and searching on this reveals a bunch of ultimately unrelated issues. What could be the cause of this? I've also tried an external USB DVD drive, but I can't seem to get the OS to recognize it. lshw shows this:
  *-cdrom                   
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVD+-RW DL-8A4SH
       vendor: PLDS
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: HD13
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open


Have you ruled out drive issues...   eg. I'd possibly boot a live system that differs significantly to your installed OS, and see how the drive performs there; ie. is it the same? or different? as that may represent hardware versus software/config.  Reason for this is mostly I've had a lot of DVD drive failures in recent three years; as DVD drives are now getting old..
